# How to open save dialog with custom file view

Tags: c#, savefiledialog

I have a save file dialog in my C# application which opens user's desktop as default:

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileAddress = new SaveFileDialog
     {
        FileName = "MyXml",
        CheckPathExists = true,
        InitialDirectory =  Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop),
        OverwritePrompt = true,
        Title = "Saveyour XML",
        AddExtension = true,
        ValidateNames = true,
        Filter = "XML Document | *.xml"
     };
```

As you see I've customized many of its options, But the one I can't figure out, is how to set default file view (thumbnail, tile, etc.. ) for it.

Is it possible programmatically?

Comment: Do you mean thumbnail, tile, etc.. view?

Comment: @raymelfrancisco yes. that. is it unclear what I'm asking?

Comment: I didn't see it before, and it will be interesting to see how you fix it.

Comment: [Link]http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16276/Customizing-OpenFileDialog-in-NET

Comment: @Sachu .. Good link, but author didn't discuss to solve what Alex is looking for... And this way will be slow too unless required otherwise..

Comment: As of now, [SaveFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't provide methods/properties for this functionality. You can edit the registry for a specific folder, [How to modify your folder view settings or to customize a folder](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/812003) (it's not recommended, but you can give it a try), or add a [desktop.ini](http://hwiegman.home.xs4all.nl/desktopini.html) file to the folder before opening it using `SaveFileDialog`.